# Prove that the set is not open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove that $$\bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}\left(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric.

For this I assumed that it is open, then for $x\in \bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}\left(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x; r)=\left\lbrace y\in \mathbb{R}: |x-y|<r \right\rbrace \subseteq \bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}\left(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$

But, i know that $$\bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}\left(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)=\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$$ whereby $$B(x; r)=\left\lbrace y\in \mathbb{R}: |x-y|<r \right\rbrace \subseteq \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$$

Clearly I appreciate that there are values for which the latter is not true, hence the possible contradiction arises, but I do not know how to formalize that to write it in the demonstration. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be a good start to choose a specific $x$. Actually, you have only one option, because the set contains only one element.

Comment: Of course, I think about taking $x=0$ so that the open ball is $B=\left\lbrace 
y \in \mathbb{R}:|y|<r \right\rbrace$, now what can i do, i think i could set some $r$ value but i don't see it clearly.

Comment: Right:  every neighborhood of $0$ leaves your set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is $\{0\}.$ For any $\epsilon> 0, 0 \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ but $\frac{\epsilon}{2} \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \backslash\{0\}$ so $0 \in \{0\}$ but there is no open neeighbourhood of $0$ that is a subset of $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $S$ of the real line is open iff for any element $x\in S$ of the su, there is an open interval containing $x$ contained $S$.  Is this true at 0?  Therein lies your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\{x\}$ is open. Then there exists some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq \{x\} \subseteq B(x,r)$, hence $B(x,r)=\{x\}$, this is a contradiction since $y=x+r/2 \in B(x,r)$ and clearly $y \neq x$.